# How to apply scrolling to the labels data in ng2-charts?

Tags: angular, ionic3

Iam working in ionic3 and angular4.I need to display pie-charts.So I used ng2-charts.I had shown labels data on right side of chart using legend position.Everything works fine but when labels data is incremented,then in legend,columns are incremented which moves the chart image to left side and in mobile view,chart disappears.Only legend data is displaying in mobile mode due to increased data.Here I need to apply scrolling to the legend so that my chart may not disappear in mobile mode having scroll option to right side legend data.This is my requirement actually.But I don't know how to apply scroll to legend data since it has no attributes resembling scrolling.Then how can I implement this requirement?
Here is my code:

```js
  public pieChartOptions:any = {
legend: {position: 'right'}
  }
```

```html
<ion-card class="w3-animate-zoom" style="background-color:white">
                    <ion-card-header style="background-color:#d9d9d9">
                        <p style="color:Black">REVENUE
                            <span style="float:right;">{{revenueSum}}</span></p>
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content padding>
                        <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType" [options]="pieChartOptions" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
                    </ion-card-content>

                </ion-card>
```